# ChromeDriver не видит элементы. А GeckoDriver видит

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Доброго времени суток!

Примерно пару недель назад ChromeDriver перестал видеть элементы сайта YouTube.
Все остальные сайты видит и отлично выполняет то, что от него требуется. Версия Драйвера - 2.41. Проверял версии до 2.3.
Вариант с тем, что поменялись идентификаторы нужных элементов отпадают, т.к. GeckoDriver видит их без проблем. На других доступных мне ПК та же ситуация.

Переходить на Gecko нет особого желания, т.к. работает заметно медленнее.

Думал, что проблема с ОС, поскольку нашлось нарушение целостности файловой системы, но данный вопрос был решён,
а вот проблемы с ХромДрайвером остались. Везде работает как надо, на YouTube начинает капризничать.

Вопрос: как исправить данную ситуацию? В чём может быть проблема? Ничего не менялось ни в коде, ни в системе, ни в плане железа.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: приведите пример кода...может просто Вам нужно простовить явное ожидание(explicit wait) и дождаться появления соответствующего элемента? Интерфейс на ютубе всётаки Polymer'ом асинхронно строится.

Comment: проверьте совместимость версии ChromeDriver и версии Chrome http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: а при чем здесь c#?

Comment: @Monomax, по всей видимости автор писал UI тесты с использованием клиента Selenium на С#.

Comment: @МихаилРебров, здравствуйте, вот код:
` IWebElement body = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body"));
body.SendKeys(Keys.PageDown);

Thread.Sleep(2500);

IWebElement input = driver.FindElement(By.Id("placeholder-area"));
input.Click(); `

Comment: @B.Vandyshev, здравствуйте, всё совместимо. Проверено и не раз.

Comment: @Eniwent,у меня нет на ютубе элемента с идентификатором `placeholder-area` ни в хроме ни в фаерфоксе... проверял и с помощью селениума и вручную в браузере. как с авторизацией так и без...как на главной странице, так и на странице с видео....этого элемента на самом деле нет.

Comment: @МихаилРебров, а какой у вас id поля ввода комментариев на странице ввода комментария? Указанный мной id - и есть неактивное поле ввода. При нажатии на данное поле, идентификатор меняется, и в моем коде это учитывается. GeckoDriver данный идентификатор находит, как ни странно. :)
Сейчас проверил с абсолютно другого ПК, еще и с анонимайзером, данный идентификатор есть.

Comment: @Eniwent, понял...смотрите..идентификатор поля комментария у меня такой же, только появляется он только после того как блок комментариев попадает в поле зрения. Т.е. данный элемент создаётся после того как вы проскролите до блока комментариев. Вы можете даже дождаться загрузки страницы и начать просматривать видео, НО, но поля для ввода комментариев там не будет, пока Вы до него не проскроллите.

Comment: @МихаилРебров, верно. Элемент не будет найден, если он не в поле зрения. Именно поэтому я передаю элементу с CssSelector'ом "body" сочетание клавиш PageDown: body.SendKeys(Keys.PageDown);

Comment: @МихаилРебров, предварительно раскрываю окно браузера на максимум. В GeckoDriver делаю те же операции. Геко видит, Хром - нет.

Comment: @Eniwent, а Вы авторизованы в хроме?

Comment: @Eniwent, добавил в ваш код авторизацию и развернул окно и всё проходит нормально...

Comment: @Eniwent, хотя у неавторизованного тоже такой элемент есть

Comment: @Eniwent, убрал авторизацию, оставил максимизированное окно...ситуация следующая: `PAGE DOWN`, срабатывает через раз....соответственно через раз получается найти это поле

Comment: @Eniwent, я написал ответ. надеюсь поможет. И приложите изначальную версию кода непосредственно в тело вопроса. Нажмите кнопку `править` и вставьте в тело поста, приведенный Вами в комментариях код...не все пользователи читают комментарии, более того часть из них по дефолту скрыта

Comment: @МихаилРебров, здравствуйте. Ваш ответ помог решить проблему. Спасибо. :)
А PageDown срабатывает всегда, если дать странице прогрузиться. По большей степени, `Thread.Sleep(2500)` и служит для этого.

Comment: @Eniwent, это хорошо:-) Я понимаю зачем был `Thread.Sleep`. Просто использование явного ожидания(`WebDriverWait`) более корректно в данном случае. Плюс при прогонке тестов явное ожидание сэкономит Вам время относительно слипа....поскольку слип будет ждать всегда то время которое вы указали, а вейт перестанет ждать если наступило указанное условие...т.е. если элемент уже есть на странице, то он не будет ждать чего то еще...он продолжит работу. Плюс в лямбду вообще все что угодно можно запихнуть - это удобно...ну и готовый набор функционала в `ExpectedConditions` облегчит задачу. Удачи Вам!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Вашем примере меня смутила следующая строка:
`Thread.Sleep(2500)`.

Так делать не стоит!

Для этого в Селениуме есть явные ожидания, которые в общем виде реализуются так:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>{ /* лямбда с условием ожидания */ });
```

Я в данном случае использовал класс `ExpectedConditions`, который уже содержит определенное количество заблаговременно подготовленных для использования в вейте функций.

В частности `ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(IWebElement element)`, которая ждёт появления элемента на странице.

После её первого использования узнал, что данный класс активно выпиливают из пакета. Он помечен `deprecated` и в целом данную фичу перенесли в отдельный пакет.

Поэтому мы ищем и устанавливаем nuget `DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers`.

В итоге ожидание появления элемента будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("content-section")));
```

Второй момент, который меня смущал, это то что не всегда срабатывал `PAGE_DOWN`.
Возможно, это из-за рекламы, которая могла перехватывать какие-либо события на странице... но тем не менее `PAGE_DOWN` я тоже решил заменить на скрол с помощью `JavaScript`:

```
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
    js.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, 1000);");
```

В результате получилось как то так:

```
    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gGIRjErhWr8");
    driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

    // скроллим на 1000 пикселей вниз
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
    js.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, 1000);");

    // ждём появления элемента #placeholder-area
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("content-section")));

    IWebElement input = driver.FindElement(By.Id("placeholder-area"));
    input.Click();
```

у меня работает как часы.